# .onmousedown executing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, onmousedown

I'm trying to have a different graph be shown when I click on a different polygon. But the function executes when the page loads, even though I defined it as `.onmousedown`.
This is the function

```
function iscrtaj(data, arg) {
    alert(arg);
    var barwidth = 13;
    var w = 700;
    var h = (barwidth + 10) * data.length;

    var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.bodovi;
        })])
        .rangeRound([0, 280]);

    var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-1, data.length])
        .range([0, h]);

    var bargraph = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 870)
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            return yscale(i);
        })
        .attr("height", barwidth)
        .attr("width", width).transition().duration(1000)
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return xscale(d.bodovi);
        })
        .attr("fill", "blue");

    svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return xscale(d.bodovi) + 910;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            return yscale(i);
        })
        .attr("dx", barwidth / 2)
        .attr("dy", "0.8em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("style", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 11; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.bodovi + " %";
        })
        .style("fill", "black");

    svg.selectAll("text.xaxis")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 830)
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            return yscale(i) + barwidth - 2;
        })
        .attr("dx", -barwidth / 2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.stranka;
        })
        .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
        .attr("class", "xaxis")
        .attr("fill", "black");
}
```

And the rest of the code on JSFiddle. (The pop-up is here just to make sure the function is taking the right arguments.)
http://jsfiddle.net/Y27NG/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.on("mousedown",iscrtaj(data1, 5))
```

calls the function instantly and the result/return if a function will be bound to the event

```
.on("mousedown",function(){iscrtaj(data1, 5);})
```

using a anonymous function like this might fix your problem, the scope and lifetime of `data` can have impact on this.

Comment: Or on ES5, use `Function#bind` (which can be polyfilled for really old engines): `.on("mousedown",iscrtaj.bind(null, data1, 5))`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure, Lately I have been using `bind` extensively especially after working with `famo.us` library.